# prepare stmt, count rows, fetch array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

I want some help with a short script I'm working on to create user IDs. I'm creating unique IDs using today's date. I run a query to the database to check if there are any IDs that contain today's date.

If there are no unique IDs with today's date, then I insert today's date as the first ID of the day. If there are IDs containing today's date, I increment that ID by 1 and INSERT that ID into the database.

It's pretty straightforward. The only problem I am having is fetching the array of the rows that contain today's date.

```
//use today's date for ID
  $idDate = date(Ymd);

  $param = "{$idDate}%";

  //retrieve all rows with today's date in ID
  $find = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid LIKE ? ");
  $find->bind_param("s", $param);
  $findresult = $find->execute();
    if(!$findresult){
     die('Invalid query : ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
      }

  $find->store_result();
```

The query is retrieving something because `num_rows` is counting at least 1 row and mysqli_error is not giving me any errors for that particular query.

```
  //count the rows
  $idcount = $find->num_rows();

  //if no rows contain today's date in IDs
  if($idcount == 0){
    $userid = $idDate . '00';
    }
    else{
```

This is giving me an error: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

```
      //store today's IDs in array
      while($found = mysqli_fetch_array($find)){
        $todaysids[] = array($found['userid']);
        }


        //find highest value 
        $hival = max($todaysids);
        //add 1 to highest value
        $userid = $hival++;
        }
```

**How can I retrieve the query result and fetch the array?**

Comment: isnt it already array ? i think you need something like $new_array[] = $found['userid'];

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing OO and procedural styles in your code. You can use `get_result` and stick to OO style:

```
$findresult = $find->execute();
$result = $find->get_result();
while ($found = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
...
```

Comment: one sidenote: this function may not be available if the mysql driver is not `mysqlnd`. should use the other way which is `$find->bind_result($col1, etc..)`. and a typo, should be `$find->get_result()` btw.

Comment: should I not use `store_result()` if I use `get_result()`?

Comment: how do I call `store_result()` and `num_rows()` now? PHP is telling me that $find is now an unexpected variable when calling those two functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count rows in your query it self like that.

```
   $find = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 , count(*) as counts FROM users WHERE userid LIKE ? ");
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--// for counting rows
   $find->bind_param("s", $param);
   $find->execute();
   $find->store_result();
   $find->bind_result( $col1 , $col2,$col3,$col4,$counts);  // bind your variables here
   $find->fetch() ;

   echo $counts ; // will give you number rows here.
   echo $col1 ;
```

edit:

```
    while($row = $find->fetch() ;)
    {
     echo $counts ; // will give you number rows here.
     echo $col1 ;
    }
```

Comment: when you use `bind_result()`, are the values returned as arrays?

Comment: @JosanIracheta it depends on how you fetch them. if you have an array of values you can use while loop. look my edit

Comment: how do I bind counts from the prepared statement? `Warning: number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

Comment: you must have same number of of binded variables with same columns and aliases selected in your query , i will edit my answer.